# Optimize for runtime

Tags: python, optimization, runtime, text-search

The following code takes in two params. An array of sentences and an array of queries. Each query has one or more words. The function below prints out index of sentence for each query that has all the words in that sentence.

This is functioning code. However, it is not optimized for large inputs because of how it is written.

How can we make it more runtime optimized? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
def textQueries(sentences, queries):
    sentences_sets = [set(s.split(' ')) for s in sentences]
    for i, words in enumerate(queries):
        results = ''
        for j, s in enumerate(sentences_sets):
            exists = True
            for word in words.split(' '):
                if word not in s:
                    exists = False
            if exists:
                results += ' %d' % j if results else '%d' % j
        if results:
            print results
        else: print -1
```

Comment: If you have working code that you'd like to have peer reviewed to help improve, then [codereview.se] was set up just for that purpose. Also, when asking a language-specific question, you should also include a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for [codereview.se]

Comment: great, here it is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217904/text-search-optimization-algo